# How to check for each value in array 1 with order, exist in array 2 and delete it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I want to take the first value of the first array and check if exist on the second array and then remove it.

For example, I want to take number 41 and delete it if it exists in any 3 arrays below if not to take number 5 and so on

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JcM5gO-uo_KtUWX8SBTWLV-SMM7iPyhT

```
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
  var num = array1[i];
  console.log('Num',num);

  for(var j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
    var eacharr = array3[j];
    for( var p = 0; p < eacharr.length; p++){
      var number = eacharr[p];
      if ( number === num) {
        eacharr.splice(i, 1);
        p--;
      }
    }
    console.log(eacharr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutating array while looping on it is not a good practice, either you use a new array to push values, or you can use `filter` and `includes`

```js
let a = [1,5,9,19, 4, 8 ,172]
let b = [5, 15,28, 99, 19]


let final = a.filter(val=> !b.includes(val))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: So I can do something like
```
let a =num; 
let b = eacharr;
```

 and loop for each num again until I reach eacharr.length =0;

Comment: @Bandock yes you can, but i am not getting your point here what you're trying to say, will you  please elaborate ?

Comment: I will be able to get back in a few hours and check it. I will reply to you as soon as possible if that work and share more if not. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I agree ***Code Maniac***'s answer, and his method is clever. `Array.prototype.includes()` determines whether the current array contains a specified value, and returns true if it is, otherwise returns false.I write his method as a function as follows, and you just need to change arr1, arr2 to your arrays.

```js
arr1 = [1, 2, 1, 3]
arr2 = [1, 3, 4]
function filterArr(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item))
}
console.log(filterArr(arr1, arr2));
```